# Cannot implicitly convert List<T> to T

Tags: c#, generics

I got following error at returns lines:

```
"Cannot implicity convert type using System.Collections.Generic.List<T> to T"
```

I do not understand why this error is thrown, my return type is IEnumerable, can you see error here?

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> Batch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, int batchSize)
    {
        List<T> nextbatch = new List<T>(batchSize);
        foreach (T item in collection)
        {
            nextbatch.Add(item);
            if (nextbatch.Count == batchSize)
            {
                yield return nextbatch;
                nextbatch = new List<T>(batchSize);
            }
        }
        if (nextbatch.Count > 0)
            yield return nextbatch;
    }
```

Comment: it seems you want to return an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` instead.

Comment: Try returning a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`

Comment: @RenéVogt  Guys you right, thank you :)

Comment: https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Batch.cs might be of interest to you

Comment: @Chris yep I know, unfortunately my team lider would not like to include another library just for Batch method, and this way seems cleaner to me than implemented in MoreLINQ, thanks though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not saying "this method will return many collections of T", you're saying "this method will return many T's".

In other words, this is how you need to declare your method:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(...)
              ^---notice 2 layers---^
```

However, assuming this method will always return lists that you don't want to retain ownership to, you should make it easier for the consumers by just stating the best type to begin with:

```
public static IEnumerable<List<T>> Batch<T>(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Method return type is `IEnumerable<T>` with **yield** should return **T** not `List<T>`

for more information on how to use yield [yield](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield)